# How to know if API v2 or v3 is used by Document Translator?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I've just migrated my Translator Hub workspace to Custom Translator. I am always using Document Translator to localize content. Document Translator doc says that it will automatically select either v2 or v3 API. Is there a way to check which version has been used?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, by changing the Category in Document Translator settings a message will be displayed which will look like this:

[click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz3p8.png)